# Notation of several functions defined identiaclly

Tags: notation

One can consider the following functions: $$f(x):X\mapsto{R}$$ $$g(x):X\mapsto{R}$$ $$h(x):X\mapsto{R}$$ Is it correct to rewrite above mentioned in the following way: $$f,g,h:X\mapsto{R}$$
or what is the appropriate way to rewrite aforementioned in more compact way?

Comment: It seems fine to me aswell

Comment: Yes, that's fine; it's common to write $f,g,h : X \to R.$ But don't use $\mapsto$ for the arrow between the domain and the codomain. Use a regular arrow like $\to$.